# Cakephp migration - schema.php could not be loaded

Tags: cakephp

Created schema file locally, using the cakephp console.

Commit/Push to repo with git.

From staging server, pull same branch.

Now, from cakephp console on staging server, trying to run "cake schema update" but get the following error;

```
Welcome to CakePHP v1.3.3 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: /var/site/app
---------------------------------------------------------------
Cake Schema Shell
---------------------------------------------------------------
Performing a dry run.
/var/site/app/config/schema/schema.php could not be loaded
```

Comment: So, what is your question? You know, that sentence ending with a question mark. Also, do you have sufficient reading permissions?

Comment: I'm logged in as root, and the schema.php file is root(owner):root(group)

Comment: May sincere apologies for not including a question mark to those confused by this :)

Comment: Can you fix the image?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For some reason I have to define the class name of the schema file, e.g.;

```
cake schema update App -f
```

Still not figured out how to run an update on a snapshot file :(

Comment: Thanks for this post! I had done exactly this, and ran into the same problem after pulling the repo to our test server. I was running the schema shell from the app directory as instructed but saw the same error. Adding the app name worked.

Comment: this happened because I generated schema from a "public_html" distro of my app. ie: my app was in a folder called "public_html" and thus   `-app: public_html -working: /home/user/public_html` is present on that host, thanks for the tip!